# If there is a positive sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\geq1}$ , s.t. $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}=e^{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_{1}=\varepsilon(>0),x_{n}=n(n\geq2),$ then $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{k+\varepsilon}{n})^{n}=e^{k+\varepsilon}>e^{k}.$$
So we have a sequence of positive numbers$\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\geq1}$ , such that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}>e^{k}.$$ In fact,for a given $k\in\mathbb{N},$ any sequence of positive numbers$\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\geq1}$  can satisfy$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}\geq e^{k}.$$ [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747987/show-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sup-limits-k-geq-n-left-frac1a-k?rq=1)

> For any given  positive integer $k$,Do we have a sequence of positive numbers$\left(x_{n}\right)_{n\geq1}$ , such that 
>   $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}=e^{k}\quad?$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n:= n-1\implies \left(\frac{x_1+x_{n+k}}{x_n}\right)^n=\left(\frac{n+k-1}{n-1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac k{n-1}\right)^n=$$

$$=\left(1+\frac k{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac k{n-1}\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^k\cdot1=e^k$$

If it is very important for you the sequence is *positive* and not merely *non-negative*, you can take the above beginning at $\;n=2\;$ .

Comment: @K.Kwai I don't understand what you don't understand...perhaps because I didn't understand correctly. Yet I think in my example (1) we have a positive sequence, and (2) I showed that $\;\lim\left(\frac{x_1+x_{n+k}}{x_n}\right)^n=e^k\;$ , which means also the limit supremum and infimum are the same as the sequence converges...DId I miss anything?

Comment: I really appreciate your reply.But in your  example,$\varliminf(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}=\varlimsup(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}=e^{1+k}\ne e^{k}$

Comment: @K.Kwai I can't see how you see such a thing: the limit of a sequence exists iff it is equal to the common value of the suplim and inflim. If my sequence **converges** then the $\;\limsup\;$ is *exactly the same* ...!

Comment: I don't know what to say.Indeed,your  sequence converges,but converges to $e^{k+1}.$So the $\limsup$ also is $e^{k+1},$ not $e^{k}.$Maybe both of us miss something from each other.

Comment: @K.Kwai Unless I am making a rather stupid mistake (wouldn't be the first time,. though...:)), I am seeing in my answer that the limit **is exactly** $\;e^k\;$ ...why do you think it is otherwise?! Can you point in my answer where is there a mistake, or where you can deduce the limit is $\;e^{k+1}\;$ ??

Comment: You have high reputation in this community that leaves me so far behind you .Don't be so modest :).  $x_{n}:=n-1$,then $x_{1}=0$(does not a positve number).We take the beginning at $n=2$,let $b_{1}=x_{2}=1;b_{n}=x_{n+1}=n (n\geq 2)\Rightarrow b_{n+k}=n+k\Rightarrow \limsup(\frac{b_{1}+b_{n+k}}{b_{n}})^{n}=e^{1+k}.$

Comment: @K The chat sucks: you can't do mathematics formulae there. If you're too worried of $\;x_1\;$ not being positive, just *shift* the sequence up one place, as I already proposed you in my answer. Now, if you really need that $\;x_1\;$ in the formula, perhaps just dividing all through $\;e\;$ may help. Right now I've no time to check this, but it is a fact that my sequence does **not** have a limsum different from what you see: its limit is what is written there...but yes: if we insist on $\;x_1\;$ positive then the limit is $\;e^{k+1}\;$ ...this is already very close to what you want, though.

Comment: There is a considerable gap  between $e^{k+1}$ and $e^{k}$.Maybe we should to prove there isn't a sequence of positive numbers，such that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{x_{1}+x_{n+k}}{x_{n}})^{n}=e^{k}$.Thank you for the time and patience you devoted to reading my messages！