# Show that $ \overline \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right)^{n} \geq \mathrm{e} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Show that
$$  \overline \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right)^{n} \geq \mathrm{e}  $$
For any sequence $\{a_n\}$ with positive terms, and that this estimate cannot be improved.

I found this problem in "Mathematical Analysis I" of Zorich, just Google Books and turn to page 149 of the preview. I believe this problem is somehow incorrectly stated (since I can't solve it :) ) , so I asked for sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/747987/42969 – Both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Climsup_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7B1%2Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Ba_%7Bn%7D%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cgeq%20e%24&p=1)

Comment: Good.Thank you.@ Approach0 @  Martin R

Comment: @Martin R  I need to delete this question?